# multiple neural network or neural network with output layer

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, mining

If outputs have correlation, what it better between output layer or multiple neural network?
like disease detection.(correlation between diabetes mellitus and obesity is high. but obesity and eye disease is low)

Comment: This might be an interesting question but I don't understand it. Please be more specific: What types of networks are you considering? What do you mean by output layer? Doesn't every neural network have some kind of output layer (even if it is the same as the input layer)?

Comment: I was wondering what is better between multiple output using 1 neural network or single output value using multiple neural networks.